# Is it possible to do a SPARQL DELETE{} WHERE{} with a FILTER(COUNT(DISTINCT ?obj) > x) in the WHERE clause?

Tags: sparql, virtuoso

I want to achieve a delete which deletes all triples where there are less than x distinct objects per subject.

The intended query should look something like this after my feeling:

```
DELETE { ?sub ?pred ?obj . } 
WHERE {  
    {SELECT ?sub ?pred ?obj (count(?obj) as ?count)
    WHERE { ?sub ?pred ?obj .
        } GROUP BY ?sub
    } FILTER(?count < 14)
}
```

The above does not work.

Also a `GROUP BY` is necessary to achieve the `?obj` per `?sub` part, but I can't figure how to do this.

Can someone push me in the right direction to solve this task?

Comment: What do you mean by 'does not work'? If there is an error message please include it in the question.

Comment: First, I think you need to get your `SELECT` right, which it doesn't appear to be. If you think your challenge may be Virtuoso-specific, please add version info, and also raise your question to the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users/), the [OpenLink Support Forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support/index.php), or an [OpenLink Support Case](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp). (ObDisclaimer: I work for [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/), maker of [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/).)

Comment: Do you just want to delete the `{ ?sub ?pred ?obj . }` triples or do you want to delete `?sub`?  If you want the latter, you will want to remove references to `?sub`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that your subquery isn't actually a legal query.  If you try to validate just the subquery on [sparql.org's query validator](http://sparql.org/validate/query), you get this output:

> Syntax error:
>
> Non-group key variable in SELECT: ?pred

Strangely enough, though, the whole query *does* validate with the [update validator](http://sparql.org/update-validator.html).  It's not exactly clear from your attempted query what exactly you're trying to delete, and the statement:

> I want to achieve a delete which deletes all triples where there are less than x distinct objects per subject.

doesn't make it perfectly clear either. If you're trying to delete triples with a subject that is related to less than 10 distinct objects over *all* the predicates used with that subject, you'd find them like this:

```sql
select ?s ?p ?o {
  ?s ?p ?o 
  { select ?s { ?s ?pp ?oo }
    group by ?s
    having (count(distinct ?oo) < 10) }
}
```

Then, extending that to do a delete is easy:

```sql
delete { ?s ?p ?o }
where {
  ?s ?p ?o 
  { select ?s { ?s ?pp ?oo }
    group by ?s
    having (count(distinct ?oo) < 10) }
}
```

Comment: You should report this as a bug to the Jena developers.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to achieve, sorry for my wage explanation. (My confusion with my query did not help to clear that up i guess) I actually ran into that. I tried the validator and was happy when it did not complain so i was not able to see what actually happened! Thank you!